# Does Excel Services support connecting / refreshing external data that comes from another workbook?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services, external-data

I'm testing Excel Service via the Excel Web Access Web Part. I managed to make a working sample of a chart that retrieves its data from a SharePoint List. However, for some reason, I can't make a chart that retrieves its data from an external workbook (uploaded in SharePoint) to connect / refresh data.

Is it not supported? Or is there an additional configuration needed?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint List OData Feed is not a supported data source for Excel services in SharePoint on Premise (But is supported in SharePoint online).so you cannot refresh the data in the browser through EWA webpart. Below are the connected data sources for Excel service on premise:

1. SQL Server tables
2. SQL Server Analysis Services cubes
3. OLE DB or ODBC data sources
4. Data models, such as those that are created in Excel

See this post about [supported data sources for On premise](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Work-with-external-data-in-Excel-Services-SharePoint-Server-a00e5a66-017e-4956-bd40-49639ad1f1d0?CorrelationId=e01b8561-cdec-491e-b3b4-37ece80cee8e&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102830785#__toc381268088)

Alternative approach is to create a power pivot chart in the workbook and display it through a EWA webpart. Make sure the workbook is connected to Power Pivot using secure store id instead of authenticated user's credentials. See this [post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/2014/10/15/powerpivot-workbook-with-a-powerpivot-connection-to-a-sharepoint-list-cannot-be-refreshed-manually-in-the-browser-data-refresh-all-connections-using-windows-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I'm not working with PowerPivot, just a regular chart. The data is retrieved from another workbook via just an external connection (OLDB). Thanks for the info though!